# GET method not getting executed in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, server

I have two files main.js & task.js , where former send api calls to all the methods defined in latter.

This main.js file is

```
const express = require('express');
let app = express();
let port = 3000

let intro = require("./routes/task.js")

app.use("/",intro)
app.listen(port,()=> console.log("we are activated"))
```

The task.js file is

```
let express = require('express')
let route = express.Router();


route.get("",(req,res) =>
{
    res.status(200).send("Welcome")
})

route.get("hello",(req,res) =>
{
    res.status(200).send("We are in Hello page")
})

module.exports = route
```

Now when I go to `localhost:3000` , I am getting the proper output i.e "welcome" is printed. However when i navigate to locahost:3000/hello , I am getting error as

```
Cannot GET /hello
```

I thought that in route , whatever we define in base route in main.js and the route path in task.js , both will get concatenated, so why my get method for "hello" is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

You still want the `/` on the path in your `router.get` call, so:

```
router.get("/hello");
```

not just `router.get("hello")`. (I've checked this locally, it fixes the problem.)

You can see that from the example in the [Router documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router) that uses `/events` on a router that is then mounted via `app.use("/calendar", router)`, which is very similar to your use case:

> Once you’ve created a router object, you can add middleware and HTTP method routes (such as get, put, post, and so on) to it just like an application. For example:
>
> ```js
> // invoked for any requests passed to this router
> router.use(function (req, res, next) {
>   // .. some logic here .. like any other middleware
>   next()
> })
>
> // will handle any request that ends in /events
> // depends on where the router is "use()'d"
> router.get('/events', function (req, res, next) {
>   // ..
> })
> ```
>
> You can then use a router for a particular root URL in this way separating your routes into files or even mini-apps.
>
> ```js
> // only requests to /calendar/* will be sent to our "router"
> app.use('/calendar', router)
> ```

Comment: But why is it so that if I go with "/" in base path and leave the router.get("hello") then it does not work. At the end it is going to join the base path and route method  so why the position of "/" impacts it ?

Comment: @BrijeshRoy - I haven't delved into the Express code. My impression from [the Route Paths documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-paths) is that route paths that aren't patterns always start with a `/`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't work because you set your base route (/) where you use the `intro`. It worked for me when I changed it to this:

```js
const express = require('express');
let app = express();
let port = 3000

let intro = require("./routes/task.js")

app.use("",intro)
app.listen(port,()=> console.log("we are activated"))
```

```js
let express = require('express')
let route = express.Router();


route.get("/",(req,res) =>
{
    res.status(200).send("Welcome")
})

route.get("/hello",(req,res) =>
{
    res.status(200).send("We are in Hello page")
})

module.exports = route
```

Comment: What they're doing is supported. A bit unnecessary in their particular example since their base path is `"/"`, but supported (basically so you can mount routes in various places). The key thing is the `/` on `"/hello"` (which you've changed but don't appear to have mentioned).

Comment: Yeah, I failed to notice that. I just followed the documentation from express, where they used a basepath, that didn't have a trailing slash and I figured that was the issue, so I moved the slash from the `use` statement to the `get` definitions. I just tried it with the slash in place in the `use` statement so it seems the issue really was that the `/` in `hello` was missing.

Comment: @ioasjfopas What I wanted to know is at the end it is going to add/concetenate whatever is present in route.get & app.use , so how does it matter if I  decide to put "/" in app.js and write simple `route.get("hello")`. It should work right , because at the end after adding it will be `/hello` only ?